# windows 10 cmd prompt change directory to drive on different physical harddrive

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, cd

I am a Windows noob here (coming from a linux background.)
I am having a problem in the cmd prompt changing to a directory on a different drive. Either I haven't found any suitable answers for this particular scenario or I'm not searching with the correct terms. Here is the scenario...

I am on `C:\` and I want to change to a directory say `E:\specific\directory`.

I know about the `/E` switch for `cd`, but it's not working in this case.
More, I have `C:\` and `D:\` on an SSD and my `E:\` is on an HDD, so they're on two different physical harddrives.

I can do

`C:\> cd /D D:\specific\directory` with no problem, but trying to

`C:\> cd /E E:\specific\directory`

I get the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

The only way it lets me on the `E:\` drive is with two commands i.e. if I do `C:\> e:` first, then it lands on the `E:\` drive, then with a second `cd` command I can navigate to whatever directory I want on `E:\`. So is there any way that I can navigate from `C:\` to a specific directory on `E:\` in one command rather than two?

Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, you should bookmark [SS64 on CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/) as an excellent on-line reference for the Windows command line - Windows still doesn't have a useful `man(1)` command...

Comment: You could use Linux on Windows 10. See [Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: Thank you @JeffZeitlin and EBGreen for your answers. However, I think you both may have missed a small detail in my question, and I also figured out what my problem was. I was using the command `C:\> cd /E E:\specific\directory` where I thought the switch flag was to use the letter for which drive you wanted to switch to, i.e. switch /E for the E:\ drive. But no, the actual flag is /D, so the command should be `C:\> cd /D E:\specific\directory`.

Comment: I was just about to post that, crob - I've been a DOS user since the 80's and I did not know about the /d option until just now after doing a cd /? and reading the help and testing it out myself.  Learned something new.

Comment: That is literally what @JeffZeitlin has in his answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `/D` switch is what you should be using. Per [SS64 on `CD`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html), `CD /D ...` changes both drive and directory - regardless of what drive you are attempting to change to - so you would use `CD /D E:\Specific\Directory`.

Answer (score 3):

As Jeff Zeitlin pointed out, you can use the /D switch however I would highly suggest using Powershell instead of cmd anyway. It is intended to be the replacement for cmd and in it this:

```
cd E:\specific\directory
```

Gives the behavior that you want. It also comes with some aliases that sort of "emmulate" *nix commands such as `ls` to make it a *"little"* more friendly to people making the transition to a windows shell.

Comment: I agree with the preference for PowerShell over cmd; however, it's not unusual for people to be irritated at answers to "how do I do this" being "don't do that, do this instead". I consider using aliases like `cd` or `ls` to be fraught with peril, however, because while they do analogous things in PowerShell, they _don't_ work the same way - `ls` might be OK, but `ls -al` isn't going to work as expected.

Comment: Well, I can't control whether someone is irritated with my answer or not. As for aliases not exactly emmulating the nix equivalent that is why *little* is in italics.